# How to execute a postgres function using a sequece cli project

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I created a project using sequelize cli npm package, I am having a hard time on how to retrieve the object that allows me to execute a postgres function. I have models and I can query a determined table but I want to execute a function.

```
const sequelize require('sequelize');

sequelize.query('myfunction') // my attempt... query is not a function
```

Comment: Try  `SELECT myfunction()`

Comment: actually it seems the object sequelize doesn't have  the query method. I am using select myfunction().

Answer (score 0):

It's like this const db = require('../models/index'), this way I can get the query method to execute.

var express = require('express');

```
const db = require('../models/index');
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', async (req, res, next)  => {

  const results = await db.sequelize.query(
    "SELECT * FROM casa_venda", 
    { 
      type: QueryTypes.SELECT 
    }
  );

  res.send(results);
  


});
```